# Python Cookie library doesn't support expire format

Tags: python, cookies

I'm trying to use the Python Cookie library, but it doesn't seem to support the standard date format (RFC 822) for the expire property. For example, in the Python prompty:

```
>>> import Cookie
>>> cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie('bcookie="123"; Expires=Sat, 14-Jun-2014 23:03:13 GMT;')
>>> cookie['bcookie']['expires']
'Sat,'
```

That is a standard header, but it processes the date up to the first space. Am I doing something wrong? I need the full expire property and would hate to have to write my own cookie library if I don't have to.

Comment: Works fine here. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Could just reproduce this with older Python versions Py2.5-

Answer (score 2):

According to Doug Hellman's excellent [Python Module of the Week site](http://blog.doughellmann.com/2008/06/pymotw-cookie.html) proper usage is

```
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
c['bcookie']['expires'] = expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S') # Wdy, DD-Mon-YY HH:MM:SS GMT
```

I can't even figure out what your argument to `SimpleCookie` is trying to do, but PyMOTW is a good secondary source as the primary documentation can be a little dense.

Comment: The project I'm building is reading the cookies from an HTTP request (via httplib2). Even the date format you're referring to breaks when the Cookie library tries to parse it. For some reason it seems to break at any space in the expires property.

Comment: The example here misses at least a line to make sense (create bcookie). And the date format is wrong with spaces instead of "-"

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this same problem. I was simply taking the `headers['set-cookie']` and creating a `Cookie.SimpleCookie`.

After a while, I realized that the site that I'm consuming from isn't quoting the date.

This is the solution I tried:

```
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie('bcookie="123"; Expires="Sat, 14-Jun-2014 23:03:13 GMT";')
```

Unfortunately, this does not solve my core problem. But, at least I understand why.